# Why is the following piece of Lua code, completely valid?

Tags: lua, luajit

From my Lua knowledge (and according to what I have read in Lua manuals), I've always been under impression that an identifier in Lua is only limited to A-Z & a-z & _ & digits (and can not start using a digit nor be a reserved keyword i.e. `local local = 123`).

And now I have run into some (obfuscated) Lua program which uses all kind of weird characters for an identifier:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiuKs.png

```lua
-- Most likely, copy+paste won't work. Download the file from https://tknk.io/7HHZ
print(_VERSION .. " " .. (jit and "JIT" or "non-JIT"))

local T = {}

T.math = T.math or {}
T.math.ď»żâ€‹â®â€‹âŞâ®â€‹­ď»żâ€Śâ€­âŽ­ = math.sin
T.math.â¬â€‹â­â¬â­â«â®â€­â€¬ = math.cos

for k, v in pairs(T.math) do print(k, v) end
```

Output:

> Lua 5.1 JIT
>   â¬â€‹â­â¬â­â«â®â€­â€¬ function: builtin#45
>   ď»żâ€‹â®â€‹âŞâ®â€‹­ď»żâ€Śâ€­âŽ­ function: builtin#44

It is unclear to me, why is this set of characters allowed for an identifier?
In other words, why is it a completely valid Lua program?

Comment: Show any online Lua example where it works.

Comment: @MikeV. What do you mean online Lua example?

Comment: Anyways, I have discovered that any Unicode character whose ASCII code is above 127 - is completely valid identifier (still no idea why is it allowed like that in Lua). This is very interesting, I'm thinking about doing my own Lua obfuscator at some point.

Comment: From 0x80 all the way up to 0xFFFF (check Unicode table). This range is full of all kind of characters, and **all of them are valid for use as part of identifier**. I just can't believe this. Could anyone explain?

Comment: For example: [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/YzOGMu) - not works. And so any online Lua compilers.

Comment: @MikeV. I have even stated my version of Lua, but I found it is irrelevant. Also, there are no online Lua compilers from what I have experience, all of them are just not working. I have Lua 5.1+5.3 and LuaJIT manually compiled from source and all are running fine on my local machine, that's the way to run Lua. Good luck trying to find any working "online Lua compiler". However, this has nothing to do with this question. I am pretty intermediate C and Lua programmer, and seeing there are no restrictions to identifiers for entire Unicode range is something completely new to me.

Comment: This is a good clarification that you have compiled Lua yourself. Maybe experts will say something more useful. I think that Lua has an artificial restriction on identifiers from ANSI characters just for compatibility.

Comment: @MikeV - LuaJIT does allow unicode characters in identifiers (unlike vanilla Lua).

Comment: "why is it a completely valid Lua program?" – What makes you think it is a completely valid Lua program rather than, for example, an *invalid* Lua program that happens to be accepted by your Lua implementation? As far as I remember, there is no requirement in the Lua spec that a Lua implementation must reject invalid programs. So, the mere fact that your program is accepted by Lua implementation does not imply that it is a completely valid Lua program.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike some languages, Lua is not really defined by a formal specification, one which covers every contingency and entirely explains all of Lua's behavior. Something as simple as "what character set is a Lua file encoded in" isn't really explain in Lua's documentation.

All [the docs say about identifiers](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1) is:

> *Names* (also called *identifiers*) in Lua can be any string of letters, digits, and underscores, not beginning with a digit and not being a reserved word.

But nothing ever really says what a "letter" is. There isn't even a definition for what character set Lua uses. As such, it's essentially implementation-dependent. A "letter" is... whatever the implementation wants it to be.

So, let's say you're writing a Lua implementation. And you want users to be able to provide Unicode-encoded strings (that is, strings *within* the Lua text). Lua 5.3 requires this. But you also don't want them to have to use UTF-16 encoding for their files (also because `lua_load` gets sequences of bytes, not shorts). So your Lua implementation assumes the byte sequence it gets in `lua_load` is encoded in UTF-8, so that users can write strings that use Unicode characters.

When it comes to writing the lexer/parser part of this implementation, how do you handle this? The simplest, easiest way to handle UTF-8 is to... *not handle UTF-8*. Indeed, that's the whole point of that encoding. Since everything that Lua defines with specific symbols are encoded in ASCII, and ASCII text is also UTF-8 text with the same meaning, you can basically treat a UTF-8 string like an ASCII string. For in-Lua strings, you just copy the sequence of bytes between the start and end characters of the string.

So how do you go about lexing identifiers? Well, you could ask the question above. Or you could ask a much simpler question: is the character a space, control character, digit, or symbol? A "letter" is merely something that *isn't one of those*.

Lua defines what things it considers to be "symbols". ASCII can tell you what is a control character, space, and a digit. In such an implementation, any UTF-8 code unit with a value outside of ASCII is a *letter*. Even if technically, those code units decode into something Unicode thinks of as a "symbol", your lexer just threats it as a letter.

This simple form of UTF-8 lexing gives you fast performance and low memory overhead. You don't have to decode UTF-8 into Unicode codepoints, and you don't need a giant Unicode table to tell you whether a codepoint is a "symbol" or "space" or whatever. And of course, it's also something that would naturally fall out of many ASCII-based Lua implementations.

So most Lua implementations will do it this way, if only by accident. Doing something more would require deliberate effort.

It also allows a user to use Unicode character sequences as identifiers. That means that someone can easily write code in their native language (outside of keywords).

But it *also* means that obfuscators have lots of ways to create "identifiers" that are just strings of nonsensical bytes. Indeed, because there are multiple ways in Unicode to "spell" the same apparent Unicode string (unless you examine the bytes directly), obfuscators can rig up identifiers that *appear* when rendered in a text editor to all be the same text, while actually being different strings.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify there is only one identifier `T`

`T.math` is sugar syntax for `T["math"]` this also extends to the obfuscate strings. It is perfectly valid to have a `key` contain any characters or even start with a number.

Now being able to use the `.` rather then `[ ]` does not work with a string that don't conform to the identifier's limitations. See Nicol Bolas' answer for a great break down of those limitations.

Comment: "*don't conform to the identifier's limitations*" What makes you think that this is true? I don't see anything that doesn't conform to what the documentation says.

Comment: @NicolBolas I am referring to having something like `T.1`(invalid) rather then `T["1"]` (valid)

Comment: My question is what makes you think that the OP's string does not conform to those limitations?

Comment: It has `<` symbols within the string

Comment: No, it does not. It has a sequence of bytes which when interpreted through UTF-8 results in a Unicode codepoint which is rendered in your browser/text editor as a glyph that *appears to be* the `<` symbol. `‹` and `<` aren't the same thing.

Comment: Oh you are very correct! I completely missed that. I will do some more research and refine my answer.